# Dependency is not satisfiable: libdevmapper1.02.1(>=2:1.02.20)

Tags: apt

I m trying to install virtualbox but ubuntu 14.04 generating an error **"Dependency is not satisfiable: libdevmapper1.02.1(>=2:1.02.20)"**
I applied this command but its not working;

```
soomaiya@soomaiya-Satellite:~$ sudo apt-get install libdevmapper1.02.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdevmapper1.02.1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
```

please share the solution for this error.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: and how are you installing *virtualbox* ? from official repo ? from oracle repo ?

Comment: You would not get the `Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6(>=2.15)` error message if you were using the default version of libc6 2.19 from the Ubuntu Software Center. If you have installed a different version of libc6 in order to install a package from a different source than from the Ubuntu repositories, such as from a PPA, then that package may not work if you try to correct your error message by installing the default version of libc6 from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I applied this code "sudo apt-get install libc6" now I m getting this error Dependency is not satisfiable: libdevmapper1.02.1(>=2:1.02.20)

Comment: Again: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 version n virtualbox installing from this site https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Can you do 'sudo apt-get upgrade' first and post the output of the last 10 lines?

Comment: Setting up python3-uno (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-ogltrans (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpurple0 (1:2.10.9-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-help-en-gb (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-help-en-us (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-presentation-minimizer (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up liboxideqtcore0:amd64 (1.3.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Processing triggers for libreoffice-common (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu1) ...

Comment: no improvement still generating same error.

Comment: I get the same error on 15.04 when trying to install virtualbox on 32-bit platform.

Answer (score 12):

You should double check the download from the Oracle site (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html). I had the same issue, but realized I download the version for 15.10 instead of 15.04 (my current Ubuntu version). When I downloaded the correct version, it installed without any problems.

Comment: This was my problem as well! Wasn't paying attention when downloading, didn't think it would make a huge difference I guess.

Comment: A source of confusion comes for the fact that the relevant .deb archive is prepared for Ubuntu 14.04. One has to read carefully the whole text to see that it is valid also for 14.10 and... 15.04!! Thank you.